# Detect Orphaned Rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following relation

```
Userfile: [id, account_id, file_id, ...]
                              |
                              v
                       File: [id, key, ...]
```

Files are stored only once on the server to save space, if a user creates a`File` (that may already exist), it is referenced by `Userfile`.

Now I want to prevent `File`s from being orphaned, when every `Userfile` row that references it has been removed.

What's the most efficient way to detect such orphaned rows in Postgres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select f.*
from
    file f
    left join
    userfile u on f.id = u.file_id
where u.file_id is null

select f.*
from file f
where not exists (
    select 1
    from userfile u
    where u.file_id = f.id
)
```

Both will detect the orphans but the second can be faster.

Comment: @Stephan The second query may (or may not) be faster because of internall postgres optimizations for `EXISTS` queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
  f.id
FROM File f
LEFT JOIN Userfile u
  ON u.file_id = f.id
WHERE 
  u.file_id IS NULL
```